# Where to ask questions about Google Play (not programming related)?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I don't know where to ask for Google Play topics.

Where can I ask questions about Google Play (not programming related)?

Comment: Are you using the Google Play website or the app through an Android device? Because the difference would determine where you ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That really depends. **Google Play** is a large topic that covers a lot of stuff, from the app store, to the music player, to the movie subscription service, to the interactive games layer, and beyond.

If your question is about part of Google Play on an Android device, you'll want to ask at [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

Be specific about the part of Google Play you're asking about.

Relevant tags:

- [google-play-store](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-store)
- [google-play-services](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-services)
- [google-play-music](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-music)
- [google-play-games](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-games)
- [google-play-books](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-books)
- [google-play-movies](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-movies)

Otherwise, if you're looking for answers from the web interface on a desktop, then [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) is the place to go.

Again, though, you probably need to distinguish between the store and other aspects.

- [google-play](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play)
- [google-play-music](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-music)
- [google-play-store](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-store)
- [google-play-books](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-books)
- [google-play-movies](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-movies)

Answer (score 1):

You can ask that question on [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in Help Center:

> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

They even have a [[google-play]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play) tag.

Comment: Not if the question is about the Google Play store on an Android device.